# Listen to pulseaudio rtp stream using VLC

Tags: networking, sound, pulseaudio, vlc

I want to listen to Pulseaudio's RTP multicast stream using VLC, but it's not working out.

First, I try to determine where it's playing:

```
tcpdump -n net 192.0.0.0/8 -c 10
```

Which gives me

```
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
13:38:07.637528 IP 192.168.1.3.53918 > 224.0.0.56.46504: UDP, length 1292
13:38:07.645170 IP 192.168.1.3.53918 > 224.0.0.56.46504: UDP, length 1292
13:38:07.651897 IP 192.168.1.3.53918 > 224.0.0.56.46504: UDP, length 1292
13:38:07.662192 IP 192.168.1.3.53918 > 224.0.0.56.46504: UDP, length 1292
13:38:07.662207 IP 192.168.1.3.53918 > 224.0.0.56.46504: UDP, length 1292
13:38:07.669482 IP 192.168.1.3.53918 > 224.0.0.56.46504: UDP, length 1292
```

So then I try to play just about every possible combination:

```
vlc rtp://@192.168.1.3
vlc rtp://@224.0.0.56
vlc rtp://@224.0.0.56.46504
```

But it just does nothing. VLC doesn't give any error messages, it seems as if it's playing, but I get no sound.

Comment: i have the same problem, any clues?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `vlc rtp://@:46504` instead.